# How can Win+S be disabled in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts

I have Windows 8.1 Preview but this applies also to Windows 8 - how can I disable <kbd>Win+S</kbd> shortcut (preferably remap it to another shortcut) but keep other <kbd>Win+X</kbd> shortcuts?

Reason for that is that I'm used to map another program to <kbd>Win+S</kbd> shortcut but this doesn't work in Windows 8 where this shortcut is assigned to system feature (Search charm). So I would like to change shortcut for Search charm to for example <kbd>Win+A</kbd> or eventually just disable it. Is it possible?

Comment: Use AutoHotkey to launch your program when that key combo is pressed.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I only don't know how to trigger Search charm from AutoHotKey.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), a free scripting utility for Windows, the remapping <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> is as simple as

```
#s::#a
```

Or if you simply want to disable <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>

```
#s::return
```

If you wish to run any program with the hotkey use

```
#s::
Run, C:\Path\to\my\program.exe
return
```

Comment: I don't know why this got downvoted, sounds like a good answer to me.

Comment: Not going to downvote, but I'm trying this on Windows 8.1, and it doesn't seem to work. Did you try this on Windows 8.1? I know that it worked on 7...

Comment: No I have not. Is it just Autohotkey that is not working, or does it not remap the combination?